# Why doesn't removeEventListener function?

Tags: javascript, events, listener, dom-events

```
var mouseListener = button2.addEventListener("mouseover", function (e) {
count++;
...
if(count > 5) button2.removeEventListener("mouseover", mouseListener);
});
```

I don't why the code doesn't work? How do I use the `removeEventListener ()` in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `listener` is the `function` you are passing in the `addEventListener` function.

```
var mouseListener = function (e) {
    count++;
    ...
    if ( count > 5 ) {
        button2.removeEventListener("mouseover", mouseListener);
    }
}

button2.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseListener);
```

Documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener